# Ellipse Pseudo element shadow css

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to add shadow to my pseudo-element but in vain. Tried many articles but still not working. My code:

```css
.ug-slick .slick-slide {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .ug-slick::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 110%;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(100% 50% at 100% 50%);
  clip-path: ellipse(70% 50% at 50% 50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px black;
        }
```

```html
<div class="ug-slick">
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you have the same styles repeated? Is that just an error in trying to paste them into the question?

Comment: @TylerH Yes sorry it was an error in pasting.

Comment: I have also tried filter:drop-shadow()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `clip-path` property you are 'clipping' a part of the visuals off, including the shadow.
Is the shape you have now the shape you want to achieve? maybe you could use `border-radius` instead of `clip-path` to create that shape.

Answer (score 0):

due to background color same as ui color change the background color like
background: #F2F2F2;

Comment: I need box-shadow on pseudo element.